# If a druid has no legs, does their wild shape form have no legs too?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, injury

I am playing a Gnome druid and my legs were lost due to an Owlbear attack.

Do my legs stay absent when I Wild Shape, or are they present when I Wild Shape but gone again when I change back?

Comment: Hi TEE, and welcome to the site! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep you're welcome to join us in chat. My commiserations to your gnome. It's a delight to see your avatar; there are multiple LGBT members on this site and in our chat, you're quite welcome here. ️‍

Comment: To think of that, your druid has no tail.

Comment: Then there's the problem of being 'legless' which is a slang term I learned from my British friends that refers to a state of having had too  much beer/wine/whisky to drink.  Puts another view on this *legless druid* ... :) but the answer still seems to cover that case.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Your wild shape forms will have legs (if it is supposed to)

Wild shape allows you to take the form of an animal.

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your action to magically assume the shape of a beast that you have seen before.

When you wild shape you take the complete form of whatever you are shaping into. The size, shape, and/or condition of your druid before they transform is irrelevant.

> Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the beast...

So, when you transform into a bear, it will be a normal four-legged bear. If you transform into a snake you will have no legs (as nature intended). Whatever form you choose, you get the normal textbook form of that animal.

## Wild shape will not bring the druid's legs back though

> You can revert to your normal form earlier by using a bonus action on your turn. You automatically revert if you fall unconscious, drop to 0 hit points, or die.

However, when you change back, your druid will have the same physical form that they had before they transformed (their "normal form"). Wild shape only allows you to transform into something else for a certain amount of time, it does not have any effects that modify your un-transformed druid self.