# Flying sidecar mechanics

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, house-rules

So here's the deal. Currently I'm playing a level 8 goliath, barb 6/fighter 2. Totem barbarian, 2nd totem is bear. Str 18. We also have a homebrew rule that allows my character to increase by a size similar to the Enlarge effect from enlarge/reduce. My character also has winged boots.

Also in the party, a bard with a constitution of 4. 19 health. The bard is our only support character.

With my winged boots, I tend to favor an airborne tactic to keep me safe from grounded enemies.
We have come to terms with the rule that you can't willingly end your turn in another creature's space. I have argued that we could rig a contraption of sorts similar to a sidecar, and I strap into a harness to carry it. The idea being to keep the bard airborne and safe with me, while being technically a square apart.

My DM's only argument against it (and I do respect that the DM's word is always final, I just want other opinions) is that "there's no mechanics for it."

I argue that the only factor that would *normally* stop other characters from doing this is carrying capacity. With my character's build, base carrying capacity is 1080 lbs. With the growth ability, 2160. Enhance ability? 4320. Carrying capacity is not a limiting factor for my character, I make it a point to carry my boat with me wherever I go.

What do y'all think?

Comment: I’ve voted to close for the moment, it isnt clear what the question is. “What do you all think” is not really an on topic question, at least, not without defining what sort of answer you are looking for. You’ve acknowledged that the rules don’t cover this, so it *seems* like you’re just soliciting opinions without clear direction about what sort of guidance you think you need.

Comment: For clarification, my question is, is there any reason in the game that this shouldn't work?

Comment: @Wtfimmortal Has your DM said that they just won't do it or only that there isn't a specific mechanic for this type of action.  Were they open to allowing it pending a direct rule or are you looking for ways to convince your DM to allow it? If the latter, that may the better question to ask: What mechanics can I present to my DM that they may consider allowing this and how should I present it?

Answer (score 10):

### Use the mounted combat rules

There are rules in the game that permit smaller creatures to ride around on larger creatures and occupy the same space already - the rules for [mounted combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountedCombat). Here's some relevant excerpts:

> A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount, using the following rules.
>
> [...]
>
> While you’re mounted, you have two options. You can either control the mount or allow it to act independently. Intelligent creatures, such as dragons, act independently.
>
> [...]
>
> An independent mount retains its place in the initiative order. Bearing a rider puts no restrictions on the actions the mount can take, and it moves and acts as it wishes.

The only not-rules-explicit leap that is required for one PC to be able to ride a larger PC as an intelligent mount is that the DM agree that the larger PC has "an appropriate anatomy", to which I think you can easily argue that a smaller character could sit on your shoulders and ride around with you.

Presuming this is allowed, the bard will be mounted on your barbarian, and then your barbarian is free to act as usual while the bard sits on their shoulders, each taking their individual turns.

If your DM's only objection to your ideas is that there aren't game mechanics to support it, then it feels like this should be an easy sell; no new mechanics are required, they just have to decide whether or not a smaller person can ride a larger person, and then all the necessary rules are right there. The wisdom of the commons, as per [this previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125050/28402) specifically covering a small PC being carried by a medium PC, is that this sort of thing should be allowed.

Comment: Master and Blaster, I love it!  